# How to give iterator-variable as param to ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have got an Array of Arrays of JToggleButtons. They are building a square and when clicked, they should call a method and give their individual coordinates as parameters. My first try looks like this:

```
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
for (final JToggleButton[] buttonRow : opponentFieldButtons) {
    col = 0;
    for (final JToggleButton button : buttonRow) {
        JToggleButton newButton = new JToggleButton("O");
        square.add(newButton);
        newButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sendCoor(row, col);
            }
        });
        opponentbg.add(Button1);
        col++;
    }
    col = 0;
    row++;
}
```

Now I get the following Error at the point where I call the method `sendCoor()`: "local variable defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final".
Normally, you could just initialise a new final int like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   final int cRow = row;
   final int cCol = col;
   sendCoor(cRow, cCol);
}
```

Bunt since we are inside a loop, these variables would also be set several times, so the Error stays the same: cRow and cCol are not effectively final.

I could create a whole new Class that implements ActionListener and create an instance of that class instead of the anonymous Class I'm using now.
But isn't there a better way to solve that?

Comment: Im confused, you *should* be able to declare temporary final variables as you mentioned, even if it's in a loop. Below `square.add(newButton)`, why couldn't you declare `final int tempRow = row;` and use that within the listener?

Comment: When I postet the question, I have only tried initialising the temp int inside the anon class. When I do it as you suggest, I get the error, that the temp int may not have been initialized. And I'm not allowed to initialise it before the loop starts and give it a value inside the loop either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just flubbed up the syntax a little bit.  Try initializing those variables at a slightly different place in your code.

```
int row = 0;
int col = 0;
for (final JToggleButton[] buttonRow : opponentFieldButtons) {
    col = 0;
    for (final JToggleButton button : buttonRow) {
        JToggleButton newButton = new JToggleButton("O");
        square.add(newButton);

        final int cRow = row;
        final int cCol = col;

        newButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                sendCoor(cRow, cCol);
            }
        });
        opponentbg.add(Button1);
        col++;
    }
    row++;
}
```

Not inside the `ActionListener`, which is what led to the error in the first place.  Declare the final variables outside the definition of the `ActionListener`, so that they are final before the `ActionListener` sees them.

Comment: This was exactly what I was trying to tell him in the comments. Should also add that the variables don't need to be declared final, as they'd be seen as "effectively final"

Comment: as already pointed out in the comments, this doesn't work either

Comment: wow my bad! I must have done something wrong the first time. Your solution seems to work! thanks :)

Comment: Yeah I dunno what you did, probably just a typo or a bad copy/pasta, but this is the normal way of doing it.  @Jere  No big deal, it's what we're here for.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Does "effectively final" work in all versions of Java?  I'm used to declaring variables explicitly like this.  Was that changed perhaps in Java 8?

Answer (score 1):

`row` and `col` are *local* variabels in your shown method.

This method is executed at "initialisation time". When the method  `actionPerformed()` of the *anonymous inner class* implementation of `ActionListener`  is called the outer method has already been left and that two variables do not exist anymore. Therefore the variables themselves cannot be used inside  `actionPerformed()`, only their *current values*. Java supports that when the local variables are final.

As long as you dont change the values Java(8) *implicity* treats them as *final* and allows to you to use their values in side the *anonymous inner class*.